# distributions with polynomials

Tags: combinatorics

How many cubic (i.e., third-degree) polynomials $f(x)$ are there such that $f(x)$ has nonnegative integer coefficients and $f(1)=9$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Essentially you want four non-negative integers to sum to $9$.  It gets slightly more complicated if you want the lead coefficient to be $>0$....in that case you have to subtract off the solutions of lower degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ where all of $a,b,c,d$ are non-negative integers.

$f(1) = 9$ implies $a + b + c + d = 9$ where $a,b,c,d \geq 0$ are integers

The number of solutions is now using the classic [stars and bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) from combinatorics

The number of polynomials is therefore,

$$
\binom{4+9-1}{9} = 220
$$

In case you wanted $a \neq 0$, then you substract off the total number of polynomials of degree $\leq 2$ which is $\binom{3+9-1}{9} = 55$

So the number of polynomials with non-zero leading co-efficient will be $220-55 = 165$